# Restrição de caractes no final de regex

Tags: php

Preciso fazer com que uma regex capture urls que só terminem com letras ou números.

Tenho essa regex aqui:

```
(https?)(:\/\/www.site.com.br)(\S){1,}
```

Do jeito que está, essa regex permite que as urls terminem com caracteres como @, !, ?, etc.

Tentei fazer isso usando lookbehind mas não consegui. Como posso fazer essa restrição de caracteres só no final da regex?

Answer (score 2):

Tente desta forma:

```
^https.+[\w]$
```

A ideia é definir âncoras no início e no final do arquivo:

- `^https`: Obriga que a URL comece com `https`;
- `[\w]$`: Obriga que a URL termine com qualquer caractere alpha numéricos, é o equivalente a `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`;
- ponto (`.`): Indica qualquer caracteres;
- mais (`+`): um ou mais caracteres